# How do I compare each column in a table using DataFrame by Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There are two tables; one is ID Table 1 and the other is Attribute Table 2.

Table 1

[image: id table 1]

Table 2

[image: attribute table 2]

If the IDs the same row in Table 1 has same attribrte, then we get number 1, else we get 0. Finally, we get the result Table 3.

Table 3

[image: result table 3]

For example, id1 and id2 have different  color and size, so the id1 and id2 row(2nd row in Table 3) has "id1 id2 0 0";

id1 and id3 have same color and different size, so the id1 and id3 row(3nd row in Table 3) has "id1 id3 1 0";

Same attribute---1
Different attribute---0

How can I get the result Table 3 using Scala dataframe?

Comment: please update the question with more clarity. for instance how does the color column changes from blue to 0 or 1 and how m in column size changes to 0 or 1?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have detailed the description, do you know how to make it?

Comment: do you have the data for table1 and tabel2 in a file? or its just that much data in the question? And thanks for the update . its clear now

Comment: yes, I have the file same as the picture in the question. In my file, id1 id2 id3 are all numbers like id1:12404, id2:3408. do you need the files?

Comment: are they in csv format?

Comment: yes, csv format. Just the same as the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val t1 = List(
  ("id1","id2"),
  ("id1","id3"),
  ("id2","id3")
).toDF("id_x", "id_y")

val t2 = List(
  ("id1","blue","m"),
  ("id2","red","s"),
  ("id3","blue","s")
).toDF("id", "color", "size")

t1
  .join(t2.as("x"), $"id_x" === $"x.id", "inner")
  .join(t2.as("y"), $"id_y" === $"y.id", "inner")
  .select(
    'id_x,
    'id_y,
    when($"x.color" === $"y.color",1).otherwise(0).alias("color").cast(IntegerType),
    when($"x.size" === $"y.size",1).otherwise(0).alias("size").cast(IntegerType)
  )
  .show()
```

Resulting in:

```
+----+----+-----+----+
|id_x|id_y|color|size|
+----+----+-----+----+
| id1| id2|    0|   0|
| id1| id3|    1|   0|
| id2| id3|    0|   1|
+----+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the table now.

Comment: hi. What if I do not know how many column in Table2, how can I make it? Such as I do not know the column name color or size. Maybe there is another column called brand. Then how can I get Table3?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it using `UDF` which helps you to understand, how ever the repetition of code and be minimized to increase the performance

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("id1", "id2"),
    ("id1","id3"),
    ("id2","id3")
  )).toDF("idA", "idB")

val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("id1", "blue", "m"),
  ("id2", "red", "s"),
  ("id3", "blue", "s")
)).toDF("id", "color", "size")

val firstJoin = df1.join(df2, df1("idA") === df2("id"), "inner")
  .withColumnRenamed("color", "colorA")
  .withColumnRenamed("size", "sizeA")
  .withColumnRenamed("id", "idx")

val secondJoin = firstJoin.join(df2, firstJoin("idB") === df2("id"), "inner")

val check = udf((v1: String, v2:String ) => {
  if (v1.equalsIgnoreCase(v2)) 1 else 0
})

val result = secondJoin
  .withColumn("color", check(col("colorA"), col("color")))
  .withColumn("size", check(col("sizeA"), col("size")))

val finalResult = result.select("idA", "idB", "color", "size")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. At first, I tried to make it use UDF, but I cannot. Your code does help me!

Comment: Great to know it helped! You can optimize the steps :)

Comment: hi. What if I do not know how many column in Table2, how can I make it? Such as I do not know the column name color or size. Maybe there is another column called brand. Then how can I get Table3?

Comment: Probably dynamically fetch all column headers as `List` from `df2`, filter out the id and iteratively call the `withColumnRenamed` and `withColumn` on the datasets.
Probably a `foldLeft` works best

Comment: Hi, Tom Lous. Would you please help me solve the question? Following is the link.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653679/how-do-i-compare-each-column-in-a-table-using-dataframe-by-scala-without-caring