# How do I compare each column in a table using DataFrame by Scala without caring what the column is？

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, udf

The question I asked before is as follows.
[Last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582222/how-do-i-compare-each-column-in-a-table-using-dataframe-by-scala)

Table 1 -- ID pairs table

[image: ID pairs table]

Table 2 -- Attribute table

[image: Attribute table]

Table 3

[image]

For example, id1 and id2 have different color and size, so the id1 and id2 row(2nd row in Table 3) has "id1 id2 0 0";

id1 and id3 have same color and different size, so the id1 and id3 row(3nd row in Table 3) has "id1 id3 1 0";

Same attribute---1 Different attribute---0

***But, what if I do not know how many attribute columns in Table2; how can I make it? Such as I do not know the column name color or size. Maybe there is another column called brand. Then how can I get Table3?***

Comment: so which columns would you want to include - all of "table2"'s columns but the `id` column?

Comment: Shouldn't you edit your original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582222/how-do-i-compare-each-column-in-a-table-using-dataframe-by-scala/44584928?noredirect=1#comment76282713_44584928

Comment: Tom Lous, thank you for reminding me. I'll see to it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution should work for any unknown number of attributes in `Table2`. I have edited the answer from your [Last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582222/how-do-i-compare-each-column-in-a-table-using-dataframe-by-scala)

```
val t1 = List(
  ("id1","id2"),
  ("id1","id3"),
  ("id2","id3")
).toDF("id_x", "id_y")

val t2 = List(
  ("id1","blue","m","brand1"),
  ("id2","red","s","brand1"),
  ("id3","blue","s","brand2")
).toDF("id", "color", "size", "brand")

val outSchema = t2.columns.tail

var t3 = t1
  .join(t2.as("x"), $"id_x" === $"x.id", "inner")
  .join(t2.as("y"), $"id_y" === $"y.id", "inner")

  for(columnName <- outSchema){
    t3 = t3.withColumn(columnName+"s", when(col(s"x.$columnName") === col(s"y.$columnName"),1).otherwise(0))
      .drop(columnName)
      .drop("id")
      .withColumnRenamed(columnName+"s", columnName)

  }
t3.show(false)
```

The final output is

```
+----+----+-----+----+-----+
|id_x|id_y|color|size|brand|
+----+----+-----+----+-----+
|id1 |id2 |0    |0   |1    |
|id1 |id3 |1    |0   |0    |
|id2 |id3 |0    |1   |0    |
+----+----+-----+----+-----+
```

The solution should work for any unknown number of attributes.

Comment: Great! New hand always be stucked by an easy problem for a long time. Thanks very much!

Comment: New hands are not experienced enough but soon they will be :). I was too like you before. Thanks for the acceptance and upvote. :)

Comment: Hi, Ramesh. How do you learn scala and spark initially? Is there any good material recommending to me except the official website？

Comment: I haven't learned it yet. Thats what i feel. You can join coursera free course for functional programming in scala. That helps a lot. :)

Comment: Thank you! Good book helps a lot, too.

Comment: yes definitely :) [Programming in Scala](http://ccfit.nsu.ru/~den/Scala/programming_in_scala_2nd.pdf) and https://gumroad.com/l/AtomicScala